# microchip exception handling

Tags: exception, microchip, pic32

While running my program on a microchip ICD3 device, the exception handling looks weird. The program will stop response while exception occurs. While checking the code, I noticed that the default-general-exception-handler.c will create an infinite loop. It is really confusing because I cannot know where the error occurs and what is the reason. Does that mean Microchip doesn't support exception handling? Or is there a way to read the error message?

infinite loop:

```
---  \home\c11067\work\C32\builds\pic32-microchip-release-1.12-20101221-rc2-20101221\pic32-libs\libc\stubs\default-general-exception-handler.c
9D00DD28  1000FFFF   beq         zero,zero,0x9d00dd28
9D00DD2C  00000000   nop
```

By defining a _general_exception_handler, it works!

```
// declared static in case exception condition would prevent
// auto variable being created
static enum {
    EXCEP_IRQ = 0,          // interrupt
    EXCEP_AdEL = 4,         // address error exception (load or ifetch)
    EXCEP_AdES,             // address error exception (store)
    EXCEP_IBE,              // bus error (ifetch)
    EXCEP_DBE,              // bus error (load/store)
    EXCEP_Sys,              // syscall
    EXCEP_Bp,               // breakpoint
    EXCEP_RI,               // reserved instruction
    EXCEP_CpU,              // coprocessor unusable
    EXCEP_Overflow,         // arithmetic overflow
    EXCEP_Trap,             // trap (possible divide by zero)
    EXCEP_IS1 = 16,         // implementation specfic 1
    EXCEP_CEU,              // CorExtend Unuseable
    EXCEP_C2E               // coprocessor 2
} _excep_code;



static unsigned int _epc_code;
static unsigned int _excep_addr;

// this function overrides the normal _weak_ generic handler
void _general_exception_handler(void)
{
    asm volatile("mfc0 %0,$13" : "=r" (_excep_code));
    asm volatile("mfc0 %0,$14" : "=r" (_excep_addr));

    _excep_code = (_excep_code & 0x0000007C) >> 2;

    while (1) {
        // Examine _excep_code to identify the type of exception
        // Examine _excep_addr to find the address that caused the exception
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.microchip.com/forums/m455278.aspx it looks like I need to define exception handling function by my self.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On most microcontrollers, there isn't any code beyond what you put there.  In most cases, if an exception occurs and you haven't defined a handler for it, the processor would have no idea how to put up a "Sorry, a system error occurred" dialog box.  Using two bytes for a "branch-to-self" instruction is enough to yield a predictable response to an exception; without particular knowledge of any better course of action, a branch-to-self or forced reset is probably as good a response as anything.

PS--Some compilers for various platforms will omit vectors for unused interrupts or exceptions; if such exceptions occur unexpectedly, weird and bizarre things can happen.  Some compilers will produce code that will force an immediate reset (note that if watchdog timer is enabled, a jump-to-self will cause a reset, eventually).  Some compilers generate an immediate return-from-interrupt (which on some CPU's may be useless, and on others can cause bad behavior).  My favorite pattern would be to have all unused interrupts make a call (not a branch) to an UnexpectedInterrupt label, which in the absence of any explicit definition will point to a branch-to-self instruction.  If one does that, an UnexpectedInterrupt handler can pop the stack and record what type of unexpected interrupt occurred.  I've not seen such a pattern, though, outside my own manually-generated interrupt vector tables.

Answer (score 2):

Just as a heads-up for further PIC32 exception debugging, the exception codes and all the bits in the 'CAUSE' register (the value you're reading into your _excep_code variable before and-ing all the other bits away) are defined in:

[PIC32 Family Reference Manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/61113C.pdf), Section 2.12.9 CAUSE Register
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/61113C.pdf